# assign CSS Border to google table row

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I am using `google visualization table` to make an table and I try to make each row has a border and implement it like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/5u7ay1jj/4/

However, the `border` CSS seems not work. How can I make it working? And also, the default `google table css` will highlight the even row, not the odd row, how does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table rows don't have borders. Assign the borders to the table cells in the rows instead.

```css
.rowodd .google-visualization-table-td {
    background-color: Linen;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
}

.rownormal .google-visualization-table-td {
    background-color: #EAF2D3;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5u7ay1jj/5/

Edit:
On reconsidering, I suspect you meant something like this, to add the borders around the rows only, not between the cells in the rows.

```css
.rowodd .google-visualization-table-td {
    background-color: Linen;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
    border-width: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.rownormal .google-visualization-table-td {
    background-color: #EAF2D3;
    border: 4px solid #000000;
    border-width: 4px 0 0 0;
}
tr:last-child .google-visualization-table-td {
    border-bottom-width:4px;
}
.google-visualization-table-td:first-child {
    border-left-width:4px;
}
.google-visualization-table-td:last-child {
    border-right-width:4px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/5u7ay1jj/6/

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574705/html-non-scroll-div-without-overflow-y-property