# html fixed div overlapped by other div

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am designing a website, inside which I want to have a `toolbar` at the top, no matter how the scroll acts, the `toolbar` div will always be at the top. This is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/85/

```
<div class="stuckpart">
    <button type="button">this button is fixed</button>
</div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

I am using `google table` js library to attach a table within the `table_div`, but When I scroll down the table, the `button` at the top is overlapped by the table. How to fix this?

To be more specific: what I want is like this what [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) did, they have a toolbar always at the top.

How would I implement something like this? A small demo in `jsfiddle` would be cool.

Comment: `position: fixed;` is the key

Comment: You haven't painted a very clear picture. Take a look at this fiddle and let me know if this is what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/AKL35/958/

Comment: don't  ask for the code on jsfiddle -- code should be in the answer -- your code should also be in the question...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/83/ @Jase Hi, here is the problem, If I scroll down, the table will overlap the fixed button.

Comment: ok, guys, please see the modified question

Comment: I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/99/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   .stuckpart{
      position:fixed;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      z-index:100
    }
```

z-index will solve your issue of overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
#nav_bar {
    position: fixed;
    background-color:blue;
    height:50px;
    width:100%
    }
#content {
    background-color:lightgreen;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    top:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oa7mfcmb/6/

Comment: it looks good, but please refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/RjHMH/85/, how can you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This will move your nav bar to the top of the page and keep it there while you scroll through the page.

```
<body>
    <div id='nav_bar'>
    </div>
</body>


#nav_bar {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   //the rest of your nav bar style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="menu"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Position `fixed` is important.